# SocketException on a "Plan Service" level on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

I am starting to see a lot of SocketException's in my Application Insights log, but from the actual machine/azure infrastruture that hosts and run my services. I am certain that it's the services that are somehow causing this but I no clue to how I can debug this any further.

The stacktrace is not really giving me a lot to work with considering it's coming from code I have no power over, since it's being thrown on the actual machine my services is hosted on:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient.StampFrontendClient+<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1+<<HttpGetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient.StampFrontendClient+<HttpRequestAsync>d__12`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient.StampFrontendClient+<HttpGetAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient.ProfilerFrontendClient+<GetEtlUploadAccessAsync>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.FrontendClient, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Uploaders.StampEtlUploader+<UploadEtlZipFileAsync>d__1.MoveNext (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Collectors.DetailedTraceCollector+<UploadTraceAsync>d__41.MoveNext (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Collectors.DetailedTraceCollector+<StopCollectingAndUploadTraceAsync>d__38.MoveNext (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Engine+<>c__DisplayClass1_1+<<RunAsync>b__2>d.MoveNext (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.Orchestration.Orchestrator+<TraceAsyncOperation>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.Orchestration, Version=2.6.1909.2701, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.Net.WebException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
```

If I look at the portal, all I see is a clue that it might come from the ApplicationInsightsProfiler, which is again nothing I have any touch with in my codebase, directly.

[image]

I am afraid I am exhausting the http connection pool somehow, but how can I further investigate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your http connections and SNAT ports please from your app open "Diagnose and solve problems" then "Availability and Performance". From there you have 2 tabs to visit: "SNAT Port Exhaustion" and "TCP Connections".
There you can see your http connections and their targets.